# Convert string into JsonObject type in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class Product with following properties:

```
public class Product  
{
    public string id  { get; set; }
    public JsonObject details { get; set; }
}
```

An example of data in details field sent using POST request is:

```
 {
   "id": "1",
   "type": "icecream",
   "name": "Vanilla Cone",
   "image":
         {
           "url": "img/01.png",
           "width": 200,
           "height": 200
         }
 }
```

I am writing unit test for this class and methods. So earlier I put this structure in a string like :

```
details = "\{ \"id\":\"1\", \"type\": \"icecream\"\}, "
```

So now it is giving me an error that it cannot convert string type to jsonObject. Is there a way to convert such string into JsonObject?

Comment: how do you convert and what is the error?\

Comment: why don't you use JObject it is flexible for string parsing

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin JObject is not supporting the nested Json structure I have.

Comment: @styx I tried this method `Org.Json.JSONObject GetJSONObject (string name);` It gave an error saying cannot convert string to JsonObject

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.json.jsonobject?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: I have also tried (JsonObject) stringValue, but it gives error as 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonValueTrimmable`1[System.string] to type System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonObject'

Comment: From Newtonsoft var result=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

Comment: I can't see any code show how you try to convert string to object. Can you show us what you have tried so far? And why do you think that it is posible to convert string to your class?

Comment: JObject is not supporting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code to convert a json string to your class

```
JsonObject jsonObj=System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(json);

Product product = new Product {id=(string) jsonObj["id"], details=jsonObj};

jsonObj.Remove("id");
```

UPDATE

if you are using array

```
    var jsonArray = JsonNode.Parse(json).AsArray();
    List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

    foreach (JsonObject jsonObj in jsonArray)
    {
        products.Add(new Product { id = (string)jsonObj["id"], details = jsonObj });

        jsonObj.Remove("id");
    }
```

Comment: Yes this worked, but it is not working for json in the form of array. Got an error in one of the type as "Cannot get the  value of a token type 'StartArray' as a object.

Comment: @Krypto456 Could you show your json in the form of array pls?

Comment: `[ {name: FooName, id : 2 }, {name :FooName2, id : 3}]` This kind of Jsonarray. , However this is working for a nested type of Json structure. I dont need to convert it to any class, just store the JsonObject directly in MongoDb

Comment: @Krypto456 Yes, but what do you want to  keep as  JsonObject? or a JsonArray? There is almost nothing except the id.

Comment: JsonObject only. I tried using JArray to put this value and then parse to JsonObject as well, but that also gave error.